# Add New column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Ok so i have data something like
[image]

i want to add a new column in the end 'Drug_NAme' and the value should be the column name
for example,in the picture, the value for cocaine says "Y", so the value in the newly added drug_name = 'Cocaine"

Trying in Pandas python

Comment: df['Drug_NAme'] ="Cocaine" try this

Comment: what if two drugs column have value as 'Y' then which one you want to consider can you show your tried code

Comment: What should happen in rows with multiple drugs? Return a list with all drugs or just one of them?  There are some rows with multiple "Y" and some without any.

Comment: Should I call the police?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple pipeline:

```
s = df.rename_axis('drugs', axis=1).stack()
df.join(s[s.eq('Y')].reset_index(1)['drugs']
        .groupby(level=0).apply(list))
```

Input:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  Y  N  N  Y
1  N  N  N  N
2  N  N  N  Y
3  Y  N  Y  Y
4  Y  Y  Y  N
5  Y  N  N  Y
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D      drugs
0  Y  N  N  Y     [A, D]
1  N  N  N  N        NaN
2  N  N  N  Y        [D]
3  Y  N  Y  Y  [A, C, D]
4  Y  Y  Y  N  [A, B, C]
5  Y  N  N  Y     [A, D]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. Although i need to understand the syntax as i am new to pandas

Comment: now can i group by the drugs column?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. You might want to use tuples instead of lists as those are hashable.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

I suppose that rows with multiple "Y" or without one are valid too. So the new column should maintain that information.

```
def get_list_drugs(row, columns_drugs):
    """Function to apply to each row in DataFrame
       This function use list comprehension
    """
    return [col for col in columns_drugs if row[col]=='Y']

# Get column names
columns_drugs = list(df.columns)    
# If there are columns with information different to drug's names 
# those should be removed
# columns_drugs.remove('ID')

df['drugs_names'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_list_drugs(row, columns_drugs), axis=1)
```

For the ten first rows this returns:

```
0              [cocaine]
1               [heroin]
2              [cocaine]
3               [heroin]
4     [heroin, fentanyl]
5                     []
6           [fentanyl_a]
7              [cocaine]
8      [heroin, ethanol]
9    [cocaine, fentanyl]
```

### Option 2

If you prefer this could be done in one line if there aren't columns different from drug's names.

```
df['drugs_names'] = df.apply(lambda r: [c for c in df.columns if r[c]=='Y'] , axis=1)
```

### Option 3

If your sample data has an error with the rows without "Y" values or with multiple "Y"s and you are interested only in ONE drug. the first one you can also get that single drug_name using index 0.

```
df['drug_name'] = df.apply(lambda r: [c for c in df.columns if r[c]=='Y'][0] , axis=1)
```

For the first five rows, you will get this.

```
0    cocaine
1     heroin
2    cocaine
3     heroin
4     heroin
```

But, you will get an error if there are rows without at least one drug with value "Y".